# MySQL: Query mutually exclusive record sets

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a mysql table similar to this:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | first    | last     +
+----+----------+-----------
|  5 | Alan     | Smith    |
|  5 | Bob      | Jones    |
|  5 | Tom      | Clark    |
|  5 | Victor   | Mars     |
|  6 | Bob      | Jones    |
|  6 | Tom      | Kelly    |
|  6 | Victor   | Mars     |
+----+----------+----------+
```

I would like to find an efficient query that can return all records that do not match between id 5 and id 6... like this:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | first    | last     +
+----+----------+-----------
|  5 | Alan     | Smith    |
|  5 | Tom      | Clark    |
|  6 | Tom      | Kelly    |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Currently, I am using 2 seperate queries that return 2 different "not in" sets that look like the following select.  Where 5 is not in 6 and where 6 is not in 5.

```
select id,
       first,
       last
  from mytable
 where id = 5  # swap 5 and 6
   and concat(first, last) 
       not in ( select concat(first, last) 
                  from mytable
                where id = 6 )   # swap 5 and 6
      group by id,
               first,
               last
```

Is there a way to get both sets in a single query and can you provide an example using this sample data?

Is there a more efficient way than my query?  Also, provide example.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `id` to mean an auto-incrementing PK. That's clearly not the case here so I've renamed that column for my own ease of comprehension...

```
SELECT x.*  
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.group_id <> x.group_id 
   AND y.first = x.first 
   AND y.last = x.last 
 WHERE x.group_id IN(5,6) 
   AND y.group_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: works and it is clean and simple and I'm sure it will be much more efficient than "not in"

Comment: The should be an `AND y.group_id IN(5,6)` in the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It does a self-join and and uses a `LEFT` join to see if there is no match.  If there is no match in the second instance of the table (`mt2`), then all of the fields from that table will return `NULL`.  Since I am guessing the `id` field is the primary key on the table, I'm guessing it should never be `NULL`.

```
select mt1.id,
       mt1.first,
       mt1.last

from mytable mt1

     LEFT JOIN mytable mt2
     ON mt1.first = mt2.first
     AND mt1.last = mt2.last
     AND mt2.id IN (5, 6)
     AND mt1.id <> mt2.id

where mt1.id IN (5, 6)
     AND mt2.id IS NULL
;
```

Comment: This did not return any result with the example table above

Comment: My bad.  Each row was matching itself.  I fixed the code above.